# How to prevent gdal_translate from overwriting existing file?

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am using `gdal_translate` to compress a Geotiff file because i found out that `gdalwarp` has known [issues](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#compressed-output) handling compression. But, I can see that `gdal_translate` does not give an error message if the output file already exist like `gdalwarp` does. How can I make   `gdal_translate` do a check if file exist before it overwrites existing one? This is useful so user don't overwrite files that are important.

See example below where I can repeat `gdal_translate` processing but `gdalwarp` throws an error.

```
$ gdal_translate -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=$tile_size -co BLOCKYSIZE=$tile_size -co compress=DEFLATE -of GTiff in.tif out_translate.tif
Input file size is 45300, 35400
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
$ gdal_translate -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=$tile_size -co BLOCKYSIZE=$tile_size -co compress=DEFLATE -of GTiff in.tif out_translate.tif
Input file size is 45300, 35400
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
$ gdalwarp -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=$tile_size -co BLOCKYSIZE=$tile_size -co compress=DEFLATE -of GTiff in.tif out_warp.tif
Creating output file that is 45300P x 35400L.
Processing in.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -9999) for image in.tif.
Copying nodata values from source in.tif to destination out_warp.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
$ gdalwarp -co TILED=YES -co BLOCKXSIZE=$tile_size -co BLOCKYSIZE=$tile_size -co compress=DEFLATE -of GTiff in.tif out_warp.tif
ERROR 1: Output dataset out_warp.tif exists,
but some command line options were provided indicating a new dataset
should be created.  Please delete existing dataset and run again.
```

I am using GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is another way to do this natively with gdal, but you could write a simple shell script that checks for the existence of the output file before executing the `gdal_translate` command. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f ${@: -1} ]; then
  echo "executing gdal_translate ..."
  gdal_translate $@
else
  echo "error: output file exists"  
fi
```

Comment: Indeed i was hoping for a native gdal way. For `gdalwarp`, there is an `-overwrite` option in that direction but i cant seen any options as such for `gdal_translate`.